# Suspend uses 25-30 seconds to go to sleep

Tags: suspend

After upgrading to 13.10, suspend takes approximately 28 seconds to complete, compared to 2-3 seconds earlier. When resuming, networking does not work and must be re-enabled by running `sudo nmcli nm sleep false` in the terminal.

When suspending with the following command, the computer goes to sleep right away (2-3 seconds) and networking works automatically after resume.

Does anyone else have the same problem? I've seen a lot of bug reports on suspend not working and networking not working after resume, but I still haven't found anyone else that has the same problem regarding the sleep delay.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I got around to it on my own. That, and most likely all the other problems as well, was caused by a third party PPA for the package called «jupiter» (basically the same as «indicator-cpufreq»). Disabling the PPA and removing «jupiter» fixed the delay and network resume issues.