# Xubuntu 20.04 - Suspend waits 30 seconds

Tags: xubuntu, suspend

This is a follow-on question to [Why does suspend in 19.04 takes 30 seconds?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138933/why-does-suspend-in-19-04-takes-30-seconds) which no one has yet answered and I am encountering the same problem on Xubuntu 20.04

System is a new desktop install of Xubuntu 20.04 from ISO and updates (64-bit). This setup calls on an encrypted /home folder from my previous Xubuntu 18.04 install (separate partition).

As in the 19.04 question above, when I select Suspend from the Whisker menu the computer remains fully active -- I can edit documents or open and close programmes -- for exactly 30 seconds before it goes into Suspend. No warnings or messages. In 18.04 Suspend took two or three seconds. Waking from Suspend in 20.04 is near-instant with no warnings or messages.

I cannot see any settings that control this behaviour, nor does Google provide any leads. This is not a deal-breaker but it's annoying. Given the exact nature of the delay, it suggests that there is a setting somewhere in a file. As a user I am confident editing settings files and using Terminal.

System is:
Xubuntu 20.04 LTS, 64-bit -
Processor = AMD A8-5600K APU with Radeon HD Graphics -
RAM = 8GB -
Legacy boot mode -
Desktop, A/C power (no battery)

Comment: I unfortunately don't have an answer, but wanted to say I have exactly the same problem. Did you do a fresh install? I upgraded from 19.10 and never had this issue. It suddenly started after the upgrade.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/385989/94704 seems to suggest it's a PPA problem. I'm going to try and disable all of mine to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Fresh install from DVD ISO and on formatted partition. I was thinking this could be a setting left over from my /home folder, but I've also used the same DVD ISO to install on an old laptop with different architecture and it has the same 30 second delay 'feature'.

Comment: PPAs are not the issue either, not on my system anyway. I have removed the two non-standard PPAs I have, tested, then put them back and tested with the same delay in place. If this is a deliberate 'feature', then why can it not be reversed in the 30 second time-out?

Comment: Yeah I've also tried to remove PPAs but no luck. I upgraded from 19.10 and didn't have that issue, it suddenly appeared after upgrading. I find that very strange. Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: On my system this delayed started with 20.04. In my case the screen lock immediately when I select suspend but there is a delay until it actually suspends. What screen locker is the system using? Check the application autostarts in the system manager.

Comment: I don't lock my screen when suspending my system and I can actually still use almost everything until ~30 seconds after clicking suspend. The only thing that happens immediately is a notification saying the network connection has ended. So it seems like that happens instantly, but then _something_ gets stuck for a bit, perhaps until that times out and the suspend process continues.

Comment: Actually I just tried something: I hit suspend, then opened some tabs in Firefox, turned networking on and off, and moved around the mouse. The suspend process didn't actually finish. The computer froze for a bit, but the screen never turned off. It was frozen for about 15 seconds, during which I used my keyboard to try and change the volume and screen brightness. When my computer unfroze the volume and brightness changed. I don't know if any of this helps but I'm so annoyed and confused by this I figured any clue might help.

Answer (score 10):

I had exactly the same behaviour on Xubuntu 20.04 after upgrade from 18.04: suspend to sleep waited for 30 sec before entering sleep mode.
Changing the lock behaviour in xfce4-screensaver did not work for me: it only had the effect that the screen went black immediately, but sleep mode still waited for 30 sec before it became active, as indicated by the power LED and disk activity LED.
What helped for me was to remove xfce4-screensaver completely:

```
killall xfce4-screensaver
sudo apt-get purge xfce4-screensaver
```

After this, sleep mode entered after 1-2 seconds again.

Comment: I'm the person from the other answer and I ended up uninstalling `xfce4-screensaver` as well. I got annoyed by having to type in my password since locking the screen was mandatory for my solution. So far so good, no odd behaviour yet. Thanks Jürgen!

Comment: It is not necessary to purge the app, `xfce4-screensaver-command --exit` will do, and uncheck the app in "Session and Startup" dialog to not start it af startup.

Comment: I like this solution. Confusing screensaver interface and/or bug in the configuration, doesn't matter. Purging the program solves the issue, and power management can still dim my screen.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me (Ubuntu 22.04 - Jammy)

Answer (score 4):

I've filed a bug report for this issue.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-screensaver/+bug/1885444

All you have to do is enabled the 'Lock Screen with System Sleep' toggle in the Lock Screen tab of the Screensaver app and restart your session (log out and log back in).

[image]

Comment: This is nor really a "solution", more a workaround. But in my case I do not wan screenlock, AT ALL (single user PC, no security concerns as I'm only working on open source software)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve this by accident. After reinstalling Xubuntu I no longer had this problem and I was happy. Unfortunately the issue reappeared, but luckily I had a fairly good recollection of what settings I had changed.

What seems to be the culprit is `xfce4-screensaver`. One of the settings I changed had to do with the lock screen, which I disabled for suspend. After that, suspend once again took 30 seconds. After re-enabling this setting (and rebooting), suspend is now instant again.

You can do this by going to Settings > Screensaver > Lock Screen > Lock screen with Screensaver (see screenshot below). Note that this setting can also be changed in Settings > Power Manager > System > Lock screen when system is going to sleep. That checkbox and the one in the screensaver settings do the same thing.

Unfortunately this does mean that you'll have to enter your password after resuming from suspend. I'm not sure yet which annoyance I prefer to keep.

It might also be possible to downgrade to an older version of `xfce4-screensaver`, but I haven't tried that.

I found [the relevant bug](https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screensaver/-/issues/45) on the XFCE GitLab. Worryingly, this person is experiencing the bug regardless of lock screen settings. I'm hoping they simply haven't rebooted, because for me it also doesn't work properly until I reboot.

I will contribute to that issue and share my experiences. I hope that others can do the same in order to help the developers solve this problem.

[image: Screensaver settings]]

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the "splash" entry in the grub menu. It helped me.

in terminal:

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Remove "splash" entry,save: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and
3. `sudo update-grub`

Comment: sudo nano /etc/default/grub        ...and remove splash...        sudo update-grub

Comment: I would not change the grub file when there are other solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the screensaver login issue noted HERE: [Disable screen locking with xubuntu 20.04 and lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246378/disable-screen-locking-with-xubuntu-20-04-and-lightdm)
If you notice, in the xfce screensaver file, there was a value  <property name="delay" type="int" value="20"/>

on mine. I reset that value (via mousepad) to "2" NOTE: save a copy before changing any values. I like to save the copy in another location such as my document file, or do a save as .old filetype (a holdover from Windows days on my part, but it works) so you can restore if needed)
You might want to review the other values in both files, it seems the screensaver and power manager are related, as well as having settings for lock screen.
You can also alter those values in the "settings editor"
found on your menu or in your Settings Manager application, if installed. This saves the original values in another file. Make sure you do not click the "reset" button for the value or it will be lost permanently, no backup.